# CSS animation not starting

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to make a loading bar with a `div`going from the left to the right.

Actually the `div` is doing nothing.

No error messages in console.

I've tried to put the keyframes declaration at the begining of the file but it's still not working.

Here is my code:

```css
@keyframes loading {
  from {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  
  to {
    margin-left: 90px;
  }
}

#loading-bar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#loading-bar > div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  animation: 3s linear 0 loading;
}
```

```html
<div id="loading-bar">
 <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 0 means 0 iteration so the animation won't run. Remove it

Comment: @TemaniAfif : Thank you, now it works well! Can you post this as an answer so I can choose it as selected answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below changes in your code. Replace `animation: 3s linear 0 loading` with `animation: loading 3s normal forwards`.

**Working code:**

```css
@keyframes loading {
  from {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 90px;
  }
}

#loading-bar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#loading-bar>div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  animation: loading 3s normal forwards;
}
```

```html
<div id="loading-bar">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I want to change `margin-left`, not `width`.

Comment: @Virinas-code I have updated my answer. pls check if that's how you wanted it to work